# How to divide the roi contours?

Tags: python, opencv, dice

I just started learning opencv and learning using python.

I have found my contours, but I want to cut into three areas because this is three dice

**original:**

[image]

**want to change like this:**

[image]

How can I fix my code?

I use VS CODE with opencv4 and python3

```py
img = cv2.imread('pic1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, \
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 51, 25)


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
  thresh,
  cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
)

cnts = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
for c in cnts:
  approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)
  area = cv2.contourArea(c)

  if area > 100:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I suspect you would need a deep learning solution with training on dice to solve that since the die are not well separate and no clear division line.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on your problem,my solution is to find external contour then divide it to 3 same size part because your objects have Identical width. but in general you have to give some more test images.

Comment: I don't know how to split it into three identical parts.
Because the dice are connected together, the white parts of the binarized image are connected.

Comment: you have a bounding box that contain 3 dices. the width of box has to divide to 3 parts